# async/await using serialport in node.js

Tags: node.js, serial-port

Working on the communication between PC and an Arduino-based Hardware with Node.js. This last device is implemented with G-Code, so if i send ‘G0’ I will receive two lines; one to confirm that the instruction has been received and a second one with data.

I would like to use async/await but something is wrong... here goes the code:

```
'use strict'
const SerialPort = require('serialport')
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline

const cardPort = new SerialPort('COM6', {
    baudRate: 115200,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    dataBits: 8,
    flowControl: false,
    usePromises: true,
}, function(err) {
    if (err){
        console.log('error: ', err.message)
        port.close()
    } else {

    }
})

const cardParser = new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' })

cardPort.pipe(cardParser)

function checkCard(port, parser){
    port.write('G0\n', function () {
        console.log('message written')
        parser.on('data', (data) => { 
            console.log(data)
            return (data)
        })
    })
}

async function run () {
    const id = await checkCard(cardPort,cardParser)
    console.log(`ID response is: ${id}`)
}

run()
```

and this is the response I got:

```
ID response is: undefined
message written
Received: G0
ENCR1PT3R!
```

why ID response is not waiting until checkCard is executed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In `checkCard` you should return `port.write`, second `async-await` works with promise and it looks like `port.write` accepts a callback rather than working on promise.

Comment: Hey OP, please consider accepting the answer below if it helped your problem; it helped me talk to - I suspect - the same controller.

Answer (score 8):

`checkCard` should return `Promise` to work, but looks like `port.write` is callback based. Enclose it in `new Promise` for it work.

```
function checkCard(port, parser){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
      port.write('G0\n', function () {
        console.log('message written')
        parser.on('data', (data) => { 
            console.log(data)
            resolve(data)
        })
      })
    });      
}
```

Comment: uhhh... I never tought I'd said it but JS is hard.
Probably harder than C++, since there are so many corner cases like this. 
This should be accepted it works... I went through the book "Node.js Design Patterns" as well to somewhat understand it

Answer (score 0):

side note: Often you'll want to use EventEmitter.once() instead of EventEmitter.on()

Listeners that only fire one time don't count towards the max listener count:
https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#handling-events-only-once