# Async communicating with serialport gives mixed data

Tags: node.js, angular, serial-port

I'm trying to communicating with an arduino that has sensors.

So i have an object called motherboard who has sensors and each sensor has metric which may have threshold and/or polling which has a methode called getValue  that sends data to the arduino and returns data with a promise. The problem is that if i async the sensors to get their values all sensors get the same value.

I don't know why this is happening. I only have programmed with javascript for 1 year and with angular for 5 months. I checked the post [async/await using serialport in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857586/async-await-using-serialport-in-node-js) but i checked my code and i did the something that was suggested in the post.

The communicate method is inside a service.

Can anyone help?

tl;dr :
send data to arduino get data back in a promise.
Metric A and B get the same promise.
The component polling also gets the promise of threshold. (metric has threshold and polling)

Me
[image: data mixed]

communication.service.ts

```
communicate(cmd: string, serialPort: SerialPort, expectedResponse: string, notExpectedResponse){
    const parser = serialPort.pipe(new Delimiter({delimiter: '\n'}));
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      serialPort.write(cmd, () => {
        console.log('message written');
        parser.on('data', data => {
          const dataString = data.toString();
          if (dataString != null && dataString.includes(expectedResponse)) {
            let responseRemoved = dataString.replace(expectedResponse + ' ', '');
            resolve(responseRemoved);
          } else {
            let response;
            if (dataString != null && dataString.includes(notExpectedResponse)) {
              response = dataString.replace(notExpectedResponse + ' ', '');
            }
            reject(response);
          }
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          reject('');
        }, this.timeOutTime);
      });
    });
}
```

threshold.component.ts

```
 private getValuesThreshold(): void{
    console.log(this.metricId);
    this.motherboardInUse.getValues(this.metricId, GlobalVariableCMD.GET_THRESHOLD_VALUES,
      GlobalVariableResponse.GET_THRESHOLD_VALUES, GlobalVariableResponse.GET_THRESHOLD_VALUES).then(data => {
      let dataString = data.toString();
      if(dataString){
        console.log(dataString);
        let responseSplit = dataString.toString().split(' ');
        let minimumValue = parseInt(responseSplit[1]);
        let maximumValue = parseInt(responseSplit[2]);
        minimumValue < this.floor ? this.minimumThreshold = this.floor : this.minimumThreshold = minimumValue;
        maximumValue > this.ceil ? this.maximumThreshold = this.ceil : this.maximumThreshold = 90;
        this.enabled = responseSplit[0].includes('1');
        console.log(this.minimumThreshold);
        console.log(this.maximumThreshold);
        console.log(this.enabled);
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      let errString = err.toString();
      if(errString){
        console.log(errString);
      }
    });
  }
```

motherboard.component.ts

```
getValuesThreshold(metricId: string, ATcmd: string, expectedResponse: string, notExpectedResponse: string) {
    let command = this.communicateBuilder.BuildCommandGetMetricValue(ATcmd, this.usedSensorId, metricId);
    console.log('motherboard get values' + command);
    let responseOk = this.commandBuilderService.respondsSuccess(expectedResponse);
    let responseNotOk = this.commandBuilderService.respondsFail(notExpectedResponse);
    return this.communicateService.communicate(command, this.motherboard.serialPort, responseOk, responseNotOk);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was sending async data with serialport.
Serialport node had no way of knowing what response was linked to what data that was send. 
So it acted on the first response it got and returned that. 
Only way to solve this was to ask them sync.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```js
async getValuesThreshold(metricId: string, ATcmd: string, expectedResponse: string, notExpectedResponse: string) {
    let command = this.communicateBuilder.BuildCommandGetMetricValue(ATcmd, this.usedSensorId, metricId);
    console.log('motherboard get values' + command);
    let responseOk = this.commandBuilderService.respondsSuccess(expectedResponse);
    let responseNotOk = this.commandBuilderService.respondsFail(notExpectedResponse);
    return await this.communicateService.communicate(command, this.motherboard.serialPort, responseOk, responseNotOk);
  }
```