# Async button in electron call an async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, electron

I have an async button on my html site. When I click the button, it should call a function, which waits for a string from my Arduino and then returns the string to the other function. If the data is saved, it should display the string on the console.

Here is the code:

```
  async function DataReceived()
  {
    await Port.parser.on('data',function(data){
    return data;
      });
  }

table.send.onclick = async () =>{
  let data = await DataReceived().then(()=> {
    if (data != "")
    {
      console.log(data);
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("too late");
    }
  })
```

Normally the function should wait for DataReceived(), but it jumps directly in the if condition and sends me back too late.
What did I do wrong? I hope you can help me.

Comment: `Port.parser.on` probably doesn't return a promise. `return data` has no effect on `DataReceived`. Check out my post [JavaScript: How (not) to get a value "out of" a callback](https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html). `async/await` and Promises are good for handling one-time async data, but are not suited for event handling.

Comment: If your `data` is set to the response of the `async` function `DataReceived`, then your `then` block shouldn't be here, you either use `async/await` or `then` notation - see the following to determine what works best for you: https://dev.to/kylejb/a-key-difference-between-then-and-async-await-in-javascript-53e9

Comment: i delete the <then>.. nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The `DataReceived()` function just registers the `on`-event, but doesn't wait for the data to occur.

You may consider moving this registration straight into the `onclick` function and add your logic to the `function` body of the `Port.parser` callback

Comment: the data is send from the arduino and after the if condition, the string displays on the console, when i write a console.log

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Felix King. You got me on the right way. The **Port.parser.on** doesn't return a promise. I had to enclose it in new Promise for it work.
a post with the answer already exist here:
[async/await using serialport in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857586/async-await-using-serialport-in-node-js)

My code looks now like this now:

```
        function DataReceived()
      {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          Port.parser.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log (data)
            resolve(data)
          })
        });
      }

 table.send.onclick = async () =>{
  let data;
  
  data = await DataReceived();

    if (data != "")
    {
      console.log(data);
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("too late");
    }
}
```